# Prove that if $x$ is element of the group G then $H = \lbrace x^n : n \in Z\rbrace$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I am looking to prove Dummit and Foote Chapter $1$ problem $27$. The other proofs I have seen are longer so I feel like there is something I'm missing or my proofs aren't as clear as they should be. This is what I have:

Associativity of H is clear since $H \subseteq G$. 
Closure of H is satisfied since $x^nx^m = x^{n+m} \in H$ as $n+m \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Since G is a group and each element $x^n$ is in $G$, $x^n$ has the inverse $x^{-n}$. Note that $x^nx^{-n} = x^{-n}x^n = e$ is in H and so H has the identity element of G. Hence H is a subgroup of G.

Comment: You don't need to check associativity when testing for a subgroup.

Comment: Your proof is correct. You don't need to note that there is associativity since it simply follows from the fact that the operation on $H$ is the same operation as on $G$. It is enough to check that $e\in H$, that $H$ is closed under the operation and that the inverse of each element in $H$ is also in $H$. There is also a shorter test: $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup if and only if $H$ is not empty and for each $x,y\in H$ the element $xy^{-1}$ is also in $H$.

Comment: Don't check if all the properties of a group are satisfied. To show that $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, you only need to prove that it is non-empty and if you have any $a, b \in H$, then the product $ab^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: I understand this better thank you.

Comment: I guess I could have noticed that $x^1 \in H$ and $x^nx^{-m} \in H$ with $n$ and $m$ integers.